# Renderer process out of memory after app is packaged into EXE

Tags: node.js, reactjs, electron, electron-packager

Expected Behavior
In my main renderer window I'm initializing UI from an imported module. When running the app in dev mode everything works but once I package the app into EXE and try to run it, I'm getting renderer process out of memory error.

The expected behavior is that the packaged app should run like the dev mode.

Actual Behavior
I've checked the electron logs and memory consumption in windows task manager. The memory usage keeps increasing until the renderer process crashes and electron logs oom error.
Since I'm new to electron I've read the documentation but unable to figure out why the same thing is running perfectly in dev mode and crashes in prod.
Log : `Renderer process oom - see https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/application-debugging for potential debugging information.`
Another log after some time : `[19156:0921/120104.184:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(440)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is swiftshader`

So this is what I'm trying to do -

Import my module which is served on localhost:

This module exposes an object - Tesseract through which I initialize my UI.

In the component which is rendered in my main browser window I initialize the UI like this:
File - index.tsx

```
useEffect(() => {
if (tsToken) {
Tesseract.ui
.init(tsToken.tsToken, "random_id")
.then((sdk: any) => {
console.log(" ~ file: index.js ~ line 3 ~ sdk", sdk);
// After this line nothing is logged and renderer process crashes (But works when I run electron in dev mode)
sdk.init({
...MasterConfig,
RootElement: document.getElementById("tesseract-root"),
});

    const authToken = sessionStorage.getItem("ts_token");
    ipcRenderer.send("set-globals", { TAC: authToken });
  })
  .catch((err: any) => console.error(err));
}
}, [tsToken]);

return <></>;
```

In the above piece of code we pass a root element to the init method. The init method then initializes a react app in that root element.

**EDIT:**
This is the init method in that module

```
SDK.prototype.init = async function (config) {
try {
  const parsedConfig = JSON.parse(this.META.uiConfig);
  window.Tesseract.ui["MasterConfig"] = merge(parsedConfig, config);
  window.Tesseract.ui["info"] = this.META;

  const projectType = window.Tesseract.ui.MasterConfig.ProjectConfig.type;
  console.log(" ~ file: lib.js ~ line 51 ~ projectType", projectType)

  const MasterConfig = window.Tesseract.ui["MasterConfig"];
  console.log(MasterConfig);
  if (
    MasterConfig &&
    MasterConfig.UserProperties &&
    MasterConfig.UserProperties.userId
  ) {
    console.log("React init here");
    // Console logs upto this point and then everything fails
    // No error logged 
    try {
      RecorderUI.ReactApp({ ...parsedConfig, ...config }).then((obj) => {
        // This is never logged
        console.log("UI rendered");
        return obj;
      }).catch(err => console.log(err));
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return err;
    }
  } else {
    const e = new Error("User Id Missing");
    e.name = "Missing unique user Id";
    throw e;
  }
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err);
  return err;
}
};
```

This is the UI rendering method:

```
export default async function entry(config) {
  // This is never logged so basically something is happening before this
  console.log("somemmthing something");
  console.log("Root Element: ", 
  window.Tesseract?.ui?.MasterConfig?.RootElement);
  try {
    const { RootElement } = config;
    RootElement.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });

    await IDBStore.create({
      version: 1,
      name: "ext",
      schema: {
        globals: "&key",
      },
    });

    const shadowRoot = RootElement.shadowRoot;
    const styleElement = document.createElement("style");
    styleElement.innerHTML = `${LoaderCss} ${SourcePreviewCSS} ${NotificationCss} ${LibraryCss} ${SelectModeCss} ${WebcamBoxCss} ${CameraBubbleCss} ${countdownCss} ${indexStyles} ${commonCss} ${colorsCss} ${homeCss} ${recordCss} ${advancedOptionsCss} ${recordingTypesCss} ${toggleOptionsCss} ${tourOverlayCss} ${headerCss} ${checkboxCss} ${tooltipCss} ${dropdownCss} ${toggleCss} ${recordButtonCss} ${bannersCss} ${toolsCss} ${canvasCss} ${paintCss} ${recordingControlsCss} ${controlsMainCss}`;
  const reactRoot = document.createElement("div");
  reactRoot.setAttribute("id", "react-root");
  shadowRoot.appendChild(styleElement);
  shadowRoot.appendChild(reactRoot);

  ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>,
    reactRoot
  );
  window.addEventListener("message", handleMessaging, false);
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err);
  return new Error(err);
}
}
```

I've read numerous blog posts, github issues but unable to find what's causing this. I need help in determining what is the difference in internal workings of electron which causes such difference b/w running in dev mode vs. packaging the app.

Comment: If you are having issues that you believe are caused by bugs, **ask them on the Electron GitHub repo**. We can't fix bugs.

Comment: Hi @IanKemp  though this is happening in an electron app but I'm 100% sure this is a node.js memory leak. I don't know much about nodejs memory leaks. I've read the basic things to check out which can cause memory leaks but no luck so far. I can explain how We've created this "Tessseract" module which initializes UI, if it helps

Comment: @IanKemp I've added the relevant methods in the questions. Can you take a look ?